# Proving that Tensor Product is Associative

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, tensor-products

I want to show that $X\otimes(Y\otimes Z)$ is isomorphic to $(X\otimes Y)\otimes Z$.

Intuitively I think I should just choose bases $\{e_{i}\}_{i\in I}, \{f_{j}\}_{j\in J}$, and $\{g_{k}\}_{k\in K}$ for $X,Y,Z$ and map

$$e_{i}\otimes(f_{j}\otimes g_{k})\mapsto (e_{i}\otimes f_{j})\otimes g_{k}$$

This defines a bijective correspondence between basis elements and so should induce a vector space isomorphism.

---

Is there a way to do this using the universal property of the tensor product?

---

$\bf{\text{Context:}}$

I am working through *Introduction to Tensor Products of Banach Spaces* by Raymond Ryan, and am working on exercises at the end of the first chapter.  I'll try to summarize what I have available.

We defined the space $X\otimes Y$ to be linear functionals on the space $B(X\times Y)$ of bilinear maps on $X\times Y$.

That is, $x\otimes y:A\mapsto A(x,y)$ for $A\in B(X\times Y)$.

We have stated and proved

$\bf{\text{Universal Property of Tensor Products}}$:  Let $X,Y,Z$ be vector spaces.  For every bilinear $A:X\times Y\to Z$ there is a unique linear map $\hat{A}:X\otimes Y\to Z$ such that $\hat{A}(x\otimes y) = A(x,y)$.

Next we proved that the Tensor product is unique up to isomorphism (in the sense of having this property).

We did not define any higher tensor product structure such as $\otimes_{i\in I}X_{i}$.

Comment: Both are isomorphic to $X\otimes Y\otimes Z$, which represents multilinear maps out of $X\times Y\times Z$.

Comment: Don't I need to first show associativity before I can even make sense of the expression $X\otimes Y\otimes Z$?  (More details on the context added to question momentarily.)

Comment: First Step: Show that, for every $x$, the mapping $(y,z)\mapsto(x\otimes y)\otimes z$ is bilinear.

Comment: Got it.  I linearize that map into a map $A_{x}:Y\otimes Z\to (X\otimes Y)\otimes Z$.

Then I linearize the map $(x,y\otimes z)\mapsto A_{x}(y\otimes z)$ to get the isomorphism.

Thanks Stefan!

Comment: That's right! Don't forget, however, that not every element of $Y\otimes Z$ is of the form $y\otimes z$.

Comment: @Kyle, this would be great if you'll post your solution (+1) from is guaranteed

Comment: @Stefan:  Thanks for the warning!  I overlooked that

Comment: @Kyle: it depends on your definitions (which I now read in your edit), but I suggested to *define* $X\otimes Y\otimes Z$ as the space representing mutilinear maps out of $X\times Y\times Z$. In any case, such a map is the same as a bilinear map out of $X\times (Y\otimes Z)$, which is the same as a bilinear map out of $(X\otimes Y)\times Z$.

Comment: @Wildildildlife:  Yeah I misread your comment at first.  I meant to post a followup comment explaining that but I must not have finalized it properly.  As I understand your hint, an alternative approach would have been to use your argument to show that $(X\otimes Y)\otimes Z\cong X\otimes Y\otimes Z\cong X\otimes (Y\otimes Z)$, right?

Comment: By the way: in my opinion it is morally very wrong to define $X\times Y$ as the dual of $B(X\times Y)$, as it confuses a space with its dual.

Comment: Yes; and if you follow the composed isomorphism $(X\otimes Y)\otimes Z\cong X\otimes Y\otimes Z\cong X\otimes (Y\otimes Z)$ you'll get precisely the isomorphism which you are describing following Stefan's hint.

Comment: How do they get confused?  I only ask out of curiousity because it's my favourite realization of the tensor product so far.

Comment: The 'correct' definition of tensor product is $\mathrm{Hom}_k(X\otimes Y,-)\cong B_k(X\times Y,-)$ (natural isomorphism of functors from vector spaces to sets). So the dual is $(X\otimes Y)^*\cong B_k(X\times Y,k)$, hence the second dual is $(X\otimes Y)^{**}\cong B_k(X\times Y,k)^*$. Using the linear injection $V\to V^{**}$ for a vector space $V$, this realizes $X\otimes Y$ as a subspace of the dual of bilinear forms on $X\times Y$. (Btw the author is Raymond Ryan, not Ray.)

Comment: Fixed.  Thanks!  As for your definition it seems to be the same one: defining $X\otimes Y$ as a set of linear functionals on $B(X\times Y)$?

Comment: I spent all day thinking about this. Is there no way to prove this using only the universal property and some diagrams, without any element-wise definitions or new definitions (like multi-linear)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here's a sketch of the argument based on the hint from Stefan Walter.

---

Start by fixing $x\in X$, and define the bilinear map $Y\times Z\to (X\otimes Y)\otimes Z$ by
$$(y,z)\mapsto (x\otimes y)\otimes z$$

By the universal property stated in my question, this induces a linear map $$A_{x}:Y\otimes Z\to (X\otimes Y)\otimes Z\text{ such that }A_{x}(y\otimes z) = (x\otimes y)\otimes z\text{ for every }y\in Y,z\in Z$$

Next define the bilinear map $X\times (Y\otimes Z)\to (X\otimes Y)\otimes Z$ by $$(x,\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}\otimes z_{i})\mapsto A_{x}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}\otimes z_{i})$$

Passing this map through the universal property yields the isomorphism.

Comment: Is there a reason to use sum $\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}\otimes z_{i}$ and not just use $y\otimes z$ like [here](https://www.du.ac.in/du/uploads/departments/mathematics/study-material/MMATH18-201%20_MT_TP.pdf)?