# Natural Isomorphism of Tensor Product With Two Rings

Tags: linear-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $A, B$ be rings, let $M$ be a $A$-module, and $N$ a $B$-module. Let $\varphi: A\rightarrow B$ be a morphism of commutative rings, and use $\varphi$ to give $N$ the structure of an $A$-module.

I'm aware that there is a natural isomorphism

$$ M\;\;\cong\;\; M\otimes_{A} A $$
and that there is a certain ``associativity'' property that the tensor product satisfies:

$$ \big(X\otimes_{A} Y\big)\otimes_{A}  Z\;\;\cong\;\; X\otimes_{A}\big(Y\otimes_{A} Z\big) $$

The question is: Does the associativity property hold when tensoring with respect to different rings? That is, is

$$ \big(M\otimes_{A} N\big)\otimes_{B} B\;\;\cong\;\; M\otimes_{A}\big(N\otimes_{B} B\big)$$
true?

Comment: If $N$ is a $B$-module, then what is $M \otimes_A N$ supposed to mean?  Can we suppose that $A$ is a subring of $B$?

Comment: Sorry, I left out an important detail. I'll augment the question.

Comment: [this argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/437814/81360)

Comment: What I meant to type is "this argument seems to work"