# Associativity of tensor product using the universal property (and not elements)

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory, tensor-products, universal-property, associativity

### My question

I thought the author of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437706/proving-that-tensor-product-is-associative?noredirect=1&lq=1) was really pushing for what I'm asking here and I don't think it was ever fully addressed in other questions (happy to be wrong!).

**My main question is** *Is there a way to prove associativity of the tensor product using only mapping diagrams and the universal property?*

---

### My setup and preferences

I'm happy to see how I didn't understand how to translate a traditional proof into this style but I don't want any uses of freeness, element analysis in the tensor product, or bases. To avoid confusion, below I'll give my definitions and be clear about what I want here.

**Categories Vect and Set:**
I assume that I have a category **Vect** whose objects are vector spaces and morphisms are linear maps, with a *forgetful functor* $\text{Fo}: {\bf Vect} \to {\bf Set}$, and that ${\bf Set}$ is a unital associative monoidal category under the cartesian product, $(X,Y) \mapsto X \times Y$. In particular below I'll use the unitor isomorphism $X \xrightarrow{i} \{\star\} \times X$. Note that the forget functor allows me to talk about when a function between vector spaces is a linear map, which I'll need below.

**Defininig bilinearity:** Next I assume that I have the following notion of *bilinear map*: Given three vector spaces $V$,$W$, and $Z$ in ${\bf Vect}$, a morphism $b: \text{Fo}(V)\times \text{Fo}(W) \to \text{Fo}(Z)$ is called bilinear if

1. for any choice of set function (i.e base point) $p: \{ \star\} \to \text{Fo}V$, the composition
   $$\text{Fo}W \xrightarrow{i} \{\star\} \times \text{Fo}W  \xrightarrow{p \times id} \text{Fo}V \times \text{Fo}W \xrightarrow{\text{Fo}b} \text{Fo}Z$$
   is in the image of the forgetful functor (i.e. is a linear map).
2. similarly for any choice of base point in $\text{Fo}W$ we have an analogous linear map.

**The universal property:**. We assume in ${\bf Vect}$ that for each pair of vector spaces $V$ and $W$ there exists a vector space $V \otimes W$ and a bilinear map $t: \text{Fo}V \times \text{Fo}W \to \text{Fo}(V \otimes W)$ satisfying:

For any vector space $Z$ and bilinear map $b: \text{Fo}V \times \text{Fo}W \to \text{Fo}Z$ there exists a unique linear map $L_b: V \otimes W \to Z$ making the induced triangular diagram in ${\bf Set}$ commute (i.e. $\text{Fo}(L_b) \circ t = b$).

---

### Why I'm so bothered by this

I see how to prove all of the following about the tensor product except for associativity.

- The tensor product is commutativity up to isomorphism
- The tensor product over $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}$ is unital up to isomorphism with unit being $\mathbb{F}$. Perhaps this is where everything falls apart, but if I assume the axioms for a vector space, we do have a pairing $\mathbb{R} \times V \to V$ and I can use this and the commutative diagrams of the axioms to achieve the result. (I almost deleted this entire question when I got to this part so feel free to pick it apart :) )
- If we had a particular choice of $V \otimes W$ so that we could change the words "there exists" to "we assign" or something, then we have a unital bifunctor on ${\bf Vect}$.

So **it seems to me** that even if I have to go out of my way to do it, there ought to be some proof for associativity in similar styles. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

In category theory tensor products are bi-functors
$$\ast \otimes \ast : \text{Mod}\!-\!A \times A\!-\!\text{Mod} \longrightarrow \text{Ab}.$$

where Ab denotes the category of abelian groups, $A$ a ring, $A$-Mod the left $A$-modules and Mod-$A$ the right $A$-modules (in your case $A = k$ your ambiant field and vector spaces are $k$-bimodules since $k$ is commutative). Its definition (unique up to natural bi-isomorphism) is given by its universal property of factorisation of bilinear maps. I won't bother rewriting it. You seem to have found a "nice" way to depict bilinear maps (but you still make choices within it).

Then the associativity is a direct consequence of the associativity of the cartesian product (you don't need to work on the elements $m \otimes n \otimes l$) so it remains to show the associativity of the cartesian product without working on elements, which seems complicated if you work with axioms of Z-F).

I don't know if it was helpful, maybe we need to make all the work for the Set category I have no idea, you can check some references e.g. book about category theory or homological algebra, it may lie within one of these...

Comment: Hi! Two questions: (1) Where are the choices I made in defining a bilinear map? (2) I'm assuming the full associativity of the cartesian product without working on elements (i.e. I have isos $(X \times Y) \times Z \xrightarrow{i_{X,Y,Z}} X \times (Y \times Z)$), so can you help me see how this lifts to Vect?

Comment: (2): When you construct your isomorphism, how do you define it without working on the elements, only by using universal properties? (I'm typing the rest wait a little) (1): It is not clear for me how restrictive you condition of not working with elements is; if you want a map ${\ast} \rightarrow X$, you must chose an element $x_0 \in X$ the one element set is final but not initial in the category Set. (3) next comment :)

Comment: I'm not constructing an isomorphism in Set. I'm just assuming I have a unital associative monoidal category structure on Set and I'm calling that product the cartesian product. I use this and the forgetful functor to define bilinearity. I see then how to prove every other piece except associativity without an element-by-element function. Does that make sense or am I making a mistake in your eyes?

Comment: Ok my mistake I thought you constructed the structure of unital associative monoidal category.

Comment: All good. I'm trying to construct it on Vect assuming I have it on Set, a forgetful functor, and the univ property... Any other thoughts welcome :)

Comment: Otherwise my idea was to create from $$(M \times N ) \times L \simeq M \times (N \times L)$$ a first iso $$(M \times N ) \otimes L \simeq M \times (N \otimes L)$$ and then a second $$(M \otimes N ) \otimes L \simeq M \otimes (N \otimes L)$$ But I used a construction of the cartesian product in Set

Comment: Right, this is the same thing I tried. But in the second line, you took the tensor product of $M \times N$ and $L$, but we're not thinking of $M \times N$ as a vector space so that's where this breaks down for me. Whereas on the right side of that same line it is fine.

Comment: To do this iso, you would need to depict an iso $\mathcal{L}_2 ((M \times N) \times L, A) \simeq M \times \mathcal{L}_2 (N \times L, A)$. Which may be possible with your definition, but I don't have more time tonight, sorry :/.

Comment: Sorry, for the vector space, it is the same definition, a vector space is a $k$-module, just change everywhere $A \leftrightarrow k$ and replace module by vector space. Indeed the problem is that you must assume that Vect is an additive category, thus the product and the sum exist and coincide. And by using your definition, you must prove it all over again...

Comment: Let me ask it this way: I don't understand the map $(M \times N) \times L \to (M \times N) \otimes L$ as this seems to assume additional structure (products). But maybe this is what is needed?

Comment: OK. If you're able to provide the proof only additionally assuming Vect is an additive category or something like this, I would happily see the proof. Still it is interesting that this was not needed for any of the other facts I listed.

Comment: Yes that's my point, it is complicated to know what you are allowed to use with new and minimalistic axioms

Comment: Maybe tomorrow sorry I don't have much free time today... Your definition is nice though!